# Can an upstream fault trip a downstream GFCI?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a GFCI outlet that trips every time it rains hard, always resets right away and rarely trips again with the same rain storm. On that breaker are two upstairs bathrooms and a garage (3 outlets total, w/ 1 GFCI in bath), all inside under roof. Plugged into that circuit is a freezer (GFCI tripped before that was added), a FIOS ONT unit powered via UPS unit and an window unit air conditioner (already eliminated as cause).

[image]

[image]

Comment: The layout of the circuit isn't clear to me from your description. A sketch would help. What's the location of the outlet that trips? Are there any GFCI outlets in sequence?

Comment: Are you sure the devices are upstream? All those connections on 1 circuit sounds like some diy work. Or a old home. Is the GFCI tripping cutting power if so they are down stream of the GFCI and that is how they work. That it resets would concern me as to why it tripped in the first place.

Comment: Is there anything attached to the LOAD terminals of the GFCI in question?

Comment: @isherwood Two story house, garage on one end, the 2 baths are upstairs on the same end, panel box in garage. GFCI outlet is in bath farthest from panel box, one non-GFCI outlet in bath #2, and one non-GFCI in garage (right beside panel box).

Comment: @Ed Beal - House built 1990, one GFCI outlet, 2 non-GFCI, trips and kill all three on circuit. That was fairly typical at the time in the case where the garage is not fully wired as I recall.

Comment: Should note there is a lot of sketchy stuff on other breakers, sun room that leaks (fed from underground cable and no GFCI), one outlet in the backyard for a pond (still haven't figured out what feeds that). Thus the upstream question.

Comment: "one GFCI outlet, 2 non-GFCI, trips and kill all three on circuit." Does this mean that the 1 GFCI trips and the other 2 outlets go dead, or does the _breaker_ trip? Can you provide a sketch showing the outlets (indicate the GFCI) and the order in which they're wired from the panel? ([Edit] your post and upload a picture by hitting the "sun & mountain" icon.)

Comment: Thanks. Please put all that information in your question.

Comment: Bathrooms in the 90’s dedicated circuit 1 or 2 if they shared a common wall defiantly not also going to the garage and other rooms.  If the sun room was attached to the house it did not need a GFCI leaking is not an electrical issue. If you can’t find the source for the pond receptacle get a receptacle tester that has a GFCI trip feature it could be fed from the load on that outside GFCI receptacle and that would be ok. I think you may be confusing upstream and downstream all devices after a GFCI that turn off when trip are downstream.

Comment: @Ed Beal - Yes, the baths share a wall, and one bath shares wall with garage. Unless the fiber optic terminal protected with UPS is tripping it, there is nothing else on the load side. So I was asking if something before (upstream) the GFCI can trip it. I would have expected the GFCI to be by the panel box with load side going to the 2 outlets, but it is the opposite, seems like a waste of cable to me.

Comment: I have seen AFCI’s trip a adjacent breaker but not a GFCI I am not saying it can’t happen but the circuitry is fairly simple the hot and neutral currents are monitored an imbalance is what causes a trip if you trip the GFCI what turns off?

Comment: Yeah, what all turns off if you push TEST on the GFCI?

Comment: It's old, no test button. But it kills the other two outlets on the circuit when it does trip. That is all I can find on that circuit.

Comment: Pulled all the connected outlets. By process of elimination, seems to be also the attic connected. Technically it's upstream.

Comment: Can you find the box in the attic that this circuit runs off to?

Comment: Yeah, just went up there a few weeks ago, all dry. Have yet to verify that the mystery run goes there. So (unless the mystery run goes to someone else's house) it is either the fios terminal (now removed from the circuit), or the attic fan getting moisture when it rains. Kind of sucks because it can go for a few days or a year without tripping.

Comment: @sapinva I'd take a look around the attic fan for signs of moisture intrusion, then

Comment: Nothing in the attic. Moved the fios thingy to another circuit and will see what happens. Apparently the big loop from the panel box to the bath and back again to right beside the panel box was just to get the attic upstream from the GFCI? Total waste of cable, would have just run the attic off of any of the bedrooms and saved 30 feet.

Answer (score 1):

A GFCI can only monitor the current passing through it. Anything that happens on its Load terminals or on the outlet itself will be detected. Anything that happens on the Line side will not. If you need to protect things further upstream, you need a GFCI further upstream, perhaps even in the breaker.